# What is the meaning of the concepts of "operator mixing" (and anomalous dimensions)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, conformal-field-theory

I am looking for an explanation about the idea of "operator mixing" and its associated concept about when [anomalous dimension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anomalous_scaling_dimension) has to be thought of as a matrix.

For example this idea is slightly touched upon in [this article](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Local_operator#Definition_of_normal_products_and_operator-mixing) though the link to anomalous dimension doesn't lead anywhere. Here they just introduce this notation of $\gamma_{kl}$ and leave it unexplained and undefined.

For some of its aspects that I want to learn about let me refer to [this article](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/ho/OPE.ps). 
I would like to understand the meaning and derivation of the equation $12$ (..that thing called $\gamma_{\phi ^2 I}$..) in the beginning of the section "Perturbative Examples" (bottom of page 5) and the argument at the top of page $7$ and equation $18$.

{...also I would like to know if this is known by some other name since I was a bit surprised to not find these two concepts in various standard QFT books like even in Weinberg's!..}

Comment: Eq. (18) is a general statement about scalars in CFTs. It expresses the fact that the OPE of two scalars consists of symmetric tensors (and no other operators), but otherwise that equation itself doesn't mean much. The (operator) functions $C_{\Delta}^{(\ell)}(x,\partial)$ are universal and can be calculated by looking at three-point functions, see for example Osborn's own paper hep-th/0011040 (but it's a useless exercise).

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky I edited the question to focus on the physics concepts of interest rather than references. Can it be reopend?
BTW since in this conctext, the concepts of "operator mixing" and anomalous dimension are very closely related, it does not hurt that the OP asks about them simultaneously in one question. So this should not be a close reason either in this case.

Comment: @DavidZaslavski In addition, it would be helpful to leave a comment for the OP about what is wrong with this generally nice higher level question and how he can fix it. The question is certainly not less salvagable than the many homework questions we get and worth a comment about why it is closed ...

Comment: @Dilaton for recent questions I leave comments, but not always on old ones. In general if an OP of an old question comes back and sees the question closed, and would like to know how to fix it up, they can always ask. Anyway, this question is still somewhat unfocused. Is it asking what operator mixing is? Or how equation 12 in the second paper was derived and what it means? Or how it relates to anomalous dimension? Each of those is a separate question, and thus we need some clarification from user6818 about what the intent is here. (Your edit does help a lot though.)

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky ok thanks for this helpful comment, agreed :-). So now it is user6818's turn to clarify further and/or make multiple nice questions out of this one. I have seen he is still active here.

Comment: I disagree with the closing of this question. It asks for definitions of terms, it mentions an equation in an article as an example of something to understand better, and it asks if they are known under other names. The upside of leaving it open is that someone might write an informative answer. What is the downside?

Comment: @MitchellPorter I agree that in my opinion the question is not that bad as it is at present. So maybe you can "flag to reopen" by explainig in the textbox of the "it needs moderator attention" option why it should be reopend? I already did this. Maybe we can gain 5 flags to reopen ... ;-)

Comment: @Mitchell this doesn't ask for a definition, it asks for an explanation, but it is not very specific about what it wants explained. Among the downsides of leaving it open are (1) that people use this as a justification to ask other unfocused questions, and (2) any answers posted may no longer apply later when the question is improved, and (3) it diminishes the site's usefulness as a place to find answers to practical questions.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky as Mitchell Porter explains the question, it seems more coherent as I was able to see first. Asking about two nearly related concepts, giving an example of what one wants to better understand from knowing these concepts, plus investigating if these two concepts are known under other terms too, is legitimate and makes a lot o sense to me too. So can the question be reopend as it is, I think it should? We did just not understand it, but Michell Porter does and maybe he can even write an answer.

Comment: @Dilaton "an example of what one wants to better understand from knowing these concepts" What concepts? That is the key issue. Right now the question asks to know "about the idea of 'operator mixing' and...anomalous dimension" but that is not a concept. What about operator mixing and anomalous dimensions does user6818 want to know? The definition? What they are used for? Some particular aspect of how they are used? That is what we need to wait for clarification on.

Comment: @MitchellPorter (and others) I have asked on [meta](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/4300/2751) if it can be reopend. Maybe you can post your thoughts there too.

Comment: I'm not competent to answer the question properly. It seems like operator mixing is about extra operators introduced by renormalization counterterms, and you have a square matrix of RGE parameters because it's really about a set of operators, where all the others arise as counterterms when you start with any one of them (so the entry Mij in the matrix would be, parameter pertaining to counterterm j when you start with operator i) ... but I got all that from Scholarpedia.

Comment: But it seems clear that the original question was one capable of drawing a completely satisfactory answer, from someone who really knows the subject and was willing to review the basics a little.

Comment: @MitchellPorter do you see? Can you write (even if it is not a comprehensive) answer now?

Comment: @Dilaton sorry. I don't understand what the moderators are thinking, I interpret closing the question as a type of tidying up that favors form over substance, why can't they just leave it so that someone can answer it some day? But that won't be me and I don't have the time to debate with them about their policies.

Comment: @MitchellPorter yes I fully agree with you, I have debated with the moderators, Manishearth though it could be left open but then they have closed it again. And David Zaslavsky said it is not experts and people who know about a physics topic that determine what is a good question from a physics point of view, but it is SE standards and policies that determine what is allowed, see his chat comment http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9816048#9816048. Physics experts hava absolutely no saying what is allowed, what are good questions, etc ... Boy how this annoyes me !

Comment: Together with the current flood of homework and very basic questions http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/4337/2751 it is particularly bad what people very knowledgable about physics say and think, such as you for example, is just ignored. And nobody cares or objects, if Physics SE becomes just a popular Physics site, as you can see from my pointless chat discussions here. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar ... :-/

Comment: If I were a mod I would take the well founded from a physics point of view opinions, words, and needs of knowledgable about physics people here much more serious, and adapt the SE rules as best as I can (and this is allowed as Shog9 said http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124915/184300) to make the site a good place for acadmics, researchers, and (univrsity) students of physics and astronomy, as the targetted audience is still described in the About) again . We have the freedom to make Physics SE a good place for this audience again, but our moderators make no use of this freedom.

Comment: I interpret the question as "what is the meaning of operator mixing? - it is hard to find any explanation via a google search".  So I think it qualifies for reopening.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Peskin and Schroeder?  It has two entries for operator mixing.

Comment: Yeah..I have seen that but as usual I find Peskin and Schroeder's exposition always kind of disparate and can't use it for anything more than an occasional reference. I am looking for something more substantial and pedagogic.

Comment: How about Zinn-Justin? From memory there is a whole chapter devoted to it, or at least something more substantial than P&S.